# Calling an ASMX service that is secured with Windows Credentials

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, windows-authentication

I've been given a Web Service (ASMX) to consume witch I need to use **Windows credentials** for.

So, I have set up my client VPN and called the WSDL, saved as an XML file and generated the proxy class using the `svcutil.exe`, so far, so good...

I'm calling the service as

```cs
// Web Service
client = new CmListSync.Models.WebCorePlayersSoapClient();
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(cUser, cPass, cDoma);
```

and in the `web.config` I have this setup:

```xml
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebCorePlayersSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="true" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" algorithmSuite="Default" negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://vm-wssrv01/players.asmx" binding="wsHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WebCorePlayersSoap" contract="WebCorePlayersSoap"
        name="WebCorePlayersSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

but when I try to call the service I get an exception saying:

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm=\"vm-wssrv01\"'.

**What am I missing?** shouldn't the service authenticate normally as I have provided the windows credentials? **What more should I do?**

What I have tried:

- **set the security mode** to **`Message`** and I got the same error as in the question above
- **set the security mode** to **`TransportWithMessageCredential`** I got: *The
  provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.\r\nParameter
  name: via*
- **set the security mode** to **`Transport`** and I got: *Binding validation failed because the WSHttpBinding does not support reliable sessions over transport security (HTTPS). The channel factory or service host could not be opened. Use message security for secure reliable messaging over HTTP.*

---

From [John Saunders](https://stackoverflow.com/users/76337/john-saunders) comment:

I have switched to `basicHttpBinding`

```xml
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebCorePlayersSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows" realm="vm-wssrv01" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://vm-wssrv01/players.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WebCorePlayersSoap" contract="WebCorePlayersSoap"
        name="WebCorePlayersSoap" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and tried changing the `security` mode to:

- `TransportWithMessageCredential`
  {"The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.\r\nParameter name: via"}
- `TransportCredentialOnly`
  {"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm=\"vm-wssrv01\"'."}
- `Message`
  {"BasicHttp binding requires that BasicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType be equivalent to the BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate credential type for secure messages. Select Transport or TransportWithMessageCredential security for UserName credentials."}
- `Transport`
  {"The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'.\r\nParameter name: via"}
- `None` 
  {"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm=\"vm-wssrv01\"'."}

I'm running out of ideas :( 
The service is HTTP only, not HTTPS and I have no Certificate to use...

Comment: ASMX web services do not support any of the WS-* standards. You must use `basicHttpBinding` with ASMX services.

Comment: @JohnSaunders good to know, and I have updated the question. Though the change, I can't still get to authenticate correctly :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

after 3 days, and with a big help from **John Saunders** as he stated that the only possible binding for an ASMX service would be `basicHttpBinding` (my search for an answer started to be much more focused) I got into this:

In the service caller, one must use the `client.ClientCredentials.UserName` as:

```cs
// Web Service
client = new CmListSync.Models.WebCorePlayersSoapClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = cUser;
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = cPass;
```

and in the configuration part, one needs to use:

```xml
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebCorePlayersSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://vm-wssrv01/players.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="WebCorePlayersSoap" contract="WebCorePlayersSoap"
        name="WebCorePlayersSoap">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for posting this. You just saved me three days of fighting this thing. When I added the Web Reference to Visual Studio, it generated two different bindings but it didn't generate the BasicHttp one, as logical and expected it would be..since it's an ASMX reference.

Comment: After banging head through a lot of posts and googling only this helped! I wish SO allows to vote up few questions and answers as many times as you want. This is that kind of a post! Removed `<identity>` part though, as it was not required in our case.